# How to get low latency sending motion data between iOS devices, and what should I expect?

Tags: ios, iphone, latency, nsstream, multipeer-connectivity

I want to control a space ship on the iPad using the accelerometer on an iPhone. The devices are connected using Multipeer Connectivity Framework. I am sending accelerometer data using the regular sendData method on the session object that links the two devices together.

Everything is working, except that there's a pretty heavy lag going on. Then I started noticiing someting weird. Messages are beeing sent in bursts, here are some logging of time elapsed between messages being recieved on the iPad.

time elapsed: 0.488062
time elapsed: 0.002678
time elapsed: 0.001255
time elapsed: 0.001652
time elapsed: 0.005365
time elapsed: 0.516167 <-- 500ms gap
time elapsed: 0.004351
time elapsed: 0.001268
time elapsed: 0.001069
time elapsed: 0.001048

And these are loggin from the controller (iphone), the sender of data:

time elapsed: 0.099938
time elapsed: 0.100045
time elapsed: 0.099997
time elapsed: 0.099978
time elapsed: 0.100027
time elapsed: 0.099975
time elapsed: 0.099997
time elapsed: 0.100296
time elapsed: 0.099719
time elapsed: 0.099567
time elapsed: 0.100650

the data is send using a timer that fires every 100ms. (10 times/sec)

with this information, I can only assume that the sending of the data is somehow buffered up and sent at another rate (seem like every 500ms) (2 times/sec).

I have also tried using NSStream version of the framework for sending data. Noticed the same kind of bursting again. Then I tried to do my own polling of the inputStream and that removed the bursting, but the latency stayed the same or higher. Feels around 500-1000ms. I dont really have a proper way of measuring the latency, but as long as its a totally worthless experience trying to control that spaceship I know its to high :)

I have very little experience doing this kind of programming so any help is appreciated. I dont even know how low of a latency to hope for in the end, but it feels like maybe a 20-50ms latency is acceptable in a game like this. And I am talking about a one way latency from the iPhone to the iPad.

Comment: Regarding the latency you are experiencing, is this ONLY from the network calls? Or do you have any other logics going on in between, like packaging your data in a NSString or similar?

Comment: I have tried both. But in the most pure version i am send one single byte just to make sure that there is nothing fishy going on. But this should not be the problem as when trying out for example the CocoaAsyncSocket library I can send full NSDictionaries packed as NSData and then unpacked on the other side again. I am getting the feeling that is has something to with threading maybe.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm running into the same problems now, six years later. I do get <20ms latency, but sometimes messages appear to be buffered and arrive delayed.

Comment: Hehe. Sorry. Looked through some of the code that I could find from the project but I cant recall if I managed to find a good solution. I remember having a support thread with apple about this, but I dont think I ever got any wiser, or maybe I have just forgotten. Sorry I cant be of any help.